# Is it possible to prove that this function $F(X)$ evaluates to $1$ for any positive integer $X$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $P_{1} = 2$, $P_{2} = 3$, $P_{3} = 5$, $P_{4} = 7$, ... (the list of all primes). Consider the function $F(x)$. It evaluates to $1$ if there exists some positive integer $N$ ( $N \ge 4$ ) such that

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{P_{N - 2}} - {P_{N - 3}} \ne {P_{N - 1}} - {P_{N - 2}}\\
{P_N} - {P_{N - 1}} = {P_{N + 1}} - {P_N},\\
{P_{N + 2}} - {P_{N + 1}} = {P_{N + 3}} - {P_{N + 2}},\\
{P_{N + 4}} - {P_{N + 3}} = {P_{N + 5}} - {P_{N + 4}},\\
 \cdots ,\\
{P_{N + 2(x - 2)}} - {P_{N + 2(x - 2) - 1}} = {P_{N + 2(x - 2) + 1}} - {P_{N + 2(x - 2)}},\\
{P_{N + 2(x - 1)}} - {P_{N + 2(x - 1) - 1}} = {P_{N + 2(x - 1) + 1}} - {P_{N + 2(x - 1)}},\\
{P_{N + 2x}} - {P_{N + 2x - 1}} = {P_{N + 2x + 1}} - {P_{N + 2x}},\\
{P_{N + 2x + 2}} - {P_{N + 2x + 1}} \ne {P_{N + 2x + 3}} - {P_{N + 2x + 2}}
\end{array} \right.$$

(note that the total number of consecutive “ $=$ ”s between two “ $\ne$ ”s is always equal to $x+1$). Otherwise, $F(x) = 0$.

I tested first $100 000$ primes and found proofs that $F(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \{ 0,1,2\}$. For example, $F(2) = 1$ because there exists $N = 4209$ such that $P_{4209} = 40063$ and

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{\rm{40037}} - {\rm{40031}} \ne {\rm{40039}} - {\rm{40037}}\\
{\rm{40063}} - {\rm{40039}} = {\rm{40087}} - {\rm{40063}},\\
{\rm{40093}} - {\rm{40087}} = {\rm{40099}} - {\rm{40093}},\\
{\rm{40111}} - {\rm{40099}} = {\rm{40123}} - {\rm{40111}},\\
{\rm{40127}} - {\rm{40123}} \ne {\rm{40129}} - {\rm{40127}}
\end{array} \right.$$

where the total number of consecutive “ $=$ ”s between two “ $\ne$ ”s is equal to $3$.

I have not found any $N$ that would prove that $F(3) = 1$, let alone $F(4)$ etc.

Can we assume that $F(x) = 1$ for any positive $x$? If yes (or no), is it possible to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this follows from standard conjectures in Number Theory, but I doubt it follows from known results. Standard conjectures imply, for example, that there are infinitely many $n$ such that each of $n,n+210,n+420,n+840,n+1260,n+1470,n+1680,n+2100,n+2520$ is prime. These would be the nine primes to satisfy your four equations, in the case $x=3$. To make them consecutive primes would just require making the odd numbers between them composite, which is a finite number of congruences with solutions by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Similarly, making the inequations you want would just be some more simple congruences.

But the smallest example might be very large.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to estimate the growth rate of the function $G(X) = P_{N}$, where $N$ is the smallest number which proves that $F(X) = 1$?

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my pay grade.

Comment: Gerry Myerson is right and this fact is called Green-Tao theroem

Comment: @Ahmad, I don't think Green-Tao is strong enough to do what I'm proposing. It's not even strong enough to guarantee that there are infinitely many primes $n$ such that $n+210$ is prime.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson you are right, my mistake because in Green-Tao theorem constants to polynomial are not allowed. thank you